# Are all ARC apps crashing?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-arc

all apps I tried to test using ARC seem to crash
I have submitted an issue(https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=528652) but it doesn't seem to be confirmed
so my question is are there apps that don't crash on ARC?

Comment: i really hope the people of google see this question as well since appearanty others can't access the issue page

Comment: Hi @Fuseteam, apps runs on arc welder, but its sometimes graphics driver which fails, i tested same app on so many computers, and some failed with puzzle icon. I am still digging into the cause of it. let me know if you find anything

Comment: @Arsalan Saleem that's strange because in my case it used to work and all of a sudden I got the puzzle face..... If I find anything I'll comment here again, I hope it gets solved

Comment: https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html?m=1 it appears this is the reason they didn't even bother :V

Comment: @Arsalan Saleem if mashed managed to make it work I think we should find a way to fork it

Answer (score 0):

since the question has been asked google ARC has been discontinued. it is no longer possible to run android apps inside of the chrome browser. the feature tis now exclusive to chromeos